# 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Failed resolution of Ljava/util/Base64 caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class "java.util.Base64"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting this error and I have read that to solve it I have to replace `import java.util.Base64` with `import android.util.Base64` but in my whole project I only found this only usage of Base68 `result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(macData);`
How should I fix it ? and also I can't replace java.util.Base64 with android.util.Base.64 cause this line of code is in the Backend

Comment: Check the whole stack trace, it usually shows you what is trying to be loaded (at least point you in the right direction). It's also quite possible that some library that you're using references that class.

Answer (score 1):

That's unfortunate - it means you're using some library, and *that* library is attempting to use `java.util.Base64`. Android picked up the java libraries as they were when android was released, which is, now, a loooong time ago. They haven't really been updated since. (That oracle v google courtcase probably wasn't helping things along...)

`j.u.Base64` was added in [java release 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) (see the 'since' line in the javadoc for this information; anything '1.6' or below, or if there is no 'since' line, is definitely available on android. Other things usually aren't). java 8 is now 7 years old, so libraries not specifically designed for android are more and more likely to start using these not-in-android library calls.

Check the stacktrace, you'll find the library that's doing this. There isn't much to do other than to stop using this library, I'm afraid. You could attempt to stick a j.u.Base64 impl in your app, but this will be relatively tricky as this may involve some legal issues, thus, either nobody does this, or if they do, they probably won't publicize how.

You could ask this library to use a third party library to do base64 work, but they may not feel like doing this, and this may not be the only problem with the library that makes it not run on android.

If the android variant is a drop-in replacement, you could rewrite the class files of this library but this too is a somewhat kludgy, hacky concept that isn't exactly difficult but because it's not a normal thing to do and usually actively disliked, I don't think you can easily find documentation on how.

Thus, the advice: Try and find another library instead.

Comment: Just for context: Android got [`java.util.Base64`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64) with API level 26, which is Android 8.0. Unfortunately Android often lags behind Java SE releases.